# It seems the file stream is not closed when it uses read command

Tags: karate

I use `read` command for some read files in the scenarios.
If the tests are running, the files can not be moved and deleted.

It seems that the file stream is not closed when it uses `read` command.
Can it close the files as declarative?

Environment:

- Karate 0.9.2

Answer (score 0):

We are also writing log files and in some cases this can cause issues, see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/661#issuecomment-458127918

But I think keeping a file lock is expected. Also we are closing files whenever we read them, but maybe we have a bug. So if you can create a sample project to replicate your problem, that would be great: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: OK, I will create the reproduction senario, and post an issue.